# How to construct cypher query for passing parameters in nodejs

Tags: parameters, neo4j, cypher

I need be able to create or update a node in neo4j. I am using node js.

I am trying to use parameters to accomplish this.

I need to construct a cypher query as in ..

```
MERGE (user:Person:User {email: {props}.email} ) 
ON CREATE user = {props} SET user.created = timestamp() 
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() 
RETURN user'
```

I have a node constructed out of query params ..

```
node={props:{name:'shekar',email:'shekar@abc.com',age:10}}
```

How do I construct the cypher query?

I am trying to construct the cypher like this ..

```
cypherQuery='MERGE (user:Person:User {email: ' + node.props.email + '}) 
ON CREATE user = ' + node.props + ' SET user.created = timestamp() 
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() 
RETURN user';
```

I get this error:

```
errorError: Invalid input '@': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or '}' (line 1, column 40)
"MERGE (user:Person:User {email: ctippur@abc.com}) ON CREATE user = [object Object] SET user.created = timestamp() ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() RETURN user"
```

- Shekar

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do this in the first place.**

Cypher has full support for named [parameters](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-parameters.html) that are used as part of the query. The parameter values are then passed in as map/json-object to the query execution.

Like you used in the first part of your question. Don't know why you abandon that in the second part of your question?

```
cypherQuery='
MERGE (user:Person:User {email: {props}.email}) 
ON CREATE SET user = {props}, user.created = timestamp() 
ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() 
RETURN user';

params = {props: {email: "foo@bar.com", name:"A name"}}
```

Comment: The whole Neo4j site seems to have been shuffled around recently.  Many, many broken links on blogs and SO posts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the emails in double quotes otherwise Cypher doesn't get it as a string:

```
... {email: "' + node.props.email + '"} ...
```

More, as you see in the error statement here:

> errorError: ... ON CREATE user = **[object Object]** SET user.created = timestamp() ON MATCH SET user.lastSeen = timestamp() RETURN user"

You are having some issue with the user too - it's just after the email so you don't see it now.

I would suggest to stringify it before passing it in the query:

```
CREATE user = ' + (JSON.stringify(node.props) + '
```

Also here, check the quotes.

As general approach I would recommend to see Micheal Hunger answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Hunger is right from a parameter handling perspective, but what your specific problem is that when you concatenated in the email address, you didn't surround with quotes - so it was inputting as {email: citippur@abc.com... instead of {email: "citippur@abc.com" ...